# viewstate and textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How is a TextBox able to persist changes (e.g. text) even after the `EnableViewState` property is set to `false` in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the ASP.NET Textbox control generates an HTML form input element `<input type="text" name="x" />`. You can verify this by looking at the source view from your browser on an ASP.NET page. When the form is posted, ASP.NET is able to read the text value from the HTTP POST contents. You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and [here](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html).

Comment: thanks jamie,
can u tell what all property of server controls are stored in viewstate?